Proof: If $B = \{b_1, ..., b_n\}$ and $ W = \{w_1, ..., w_n \}$ are basis of a vectorspace, then so is $\{b_1, ..., b_{k-1}, w_{k}, ..., w_{n}\}$.
I have some questions regarding the soundness of my reasoning in the following proof:

Proposition: Let $V$ be a (finite) vector space over $F$ with the
bases $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n\},\ W = \{w_1, w_2,\ \ldots w_n\},$
with $n:=\vert B \vert \geq 2.$ Then there exists $B'\subset B$ with
$k:=\vert B'\vert\geq 2,$ and $W'\subset W$ with $\vert W'\vert =
 n-k,$ such that $B'\cup W'$ is a basis of $V.$

My proof: We may use the following statement:
"Let $V$ be a vector space over F with a basis $B$ consisting of the linearly independent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_r$, and let $x \in V, x \neq 0$. Then there exists an index $j \in \{1, \ldots, r\}$ such that the set
$$
\left\{v_1, \ldots, v_{j-1}, x, v_{j+1}, \ldots, v_r\right\}
$$
also forms a basis of $V$.'' (this was proven by the lecturer)
As $W$ is a basis and as such linearly independent, we have $ w_n \neq 0$. By the above theorem it then follows that there exists a $b_j\in B$ such that $A_1 = (B \setminus \{b_j\}) \cup \{w_n\}$ is a basis of $V$. Without loss of generality, let $b_j = b_n$ (otherwise rename the vectors (note: is this step ok?)). We also have $w_{n-1}\neq 0$. Again by above statement, there is an $a\in A$ such that $(A\setminus \{a\})\cup \{w_{n-1}\}$ is a basis of $V$. It cannot be the case that $a = w_n$, as $w_n$ and $w_{n-1}$ are linearly independent (this was said by the lecturer (I THINK), but I have tried to prove that $a \neq w_n$ by contradiction, but did not get particularly far...is this reasoning sound, and if so, why? Or where might I look for my contradiction?) by virtue of being elements of the basis $W$. Repeating this until we get to $w_k \neq 0$ gives us the proposition.

Your title has ${b_1, ..., b_{k-1}, w_{k}, ..., w_{n}}$. whereas your question has  ${b_1, ..., b_{k-1}, w_k, ..., w_{k-1}}.$ Which one is it? I'd guess the former, as the latter is silly. If it is the former, then the proposition is false: one counter-example already arises in $V=\mathbb{R}^2: b_1 = (0,1), b_2 = (1,0), w_1 = (1,0), w_2 = (0,1).$

You clarified the question. But my counter-example still holds, no?

I am pretty sure it does, but my confusion arises from the fact that surely we could just "rename" the vectors in W and then we would get {(0,1), (1,0)}, a basis of $\mathbb R^2$?

Ah, well that's more interesting. Is it OK if I amend your question so that your question is as intended?

@AdamRubinson please do

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma
